# Is there any way to have a function when a member leaves a voice channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to have a function when a member leaves a voice channel? Basically like:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_vc_leave(member):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update), and then you just have to check whether the new state is in or out of the channel in question/any channel